# PHP - How can i create a BASH script and let it run as new process?

Tags: php, bash, zend-framework

I have a queue list (created in Zend Framework PHP and stored in MySQL) which need to be deliver to a receiver (Pager, Arduino, Microcontrollers).

but the receiver can be switched off (power failure or not connected to power) or no network (wifi not available or cable is unplugged).

Later once its (the device) available/online. PHP should sent from server to the device (not device will be doing the crawling, because the device only have one listening port as server mode on TCP protocol).

So, i have to from PHP create a BASH script and run it as new process with loop. How do you do that? here is a rough sample what i mean:

New process as job:

```
$ cat /var/tmp/job1.sh
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
  # by triggering this it will send a TCP command to the device for downloading the new job

  #curl "http://myphpserver/controller/action?valuesfromPHP1=1&valuesfromPHP2=2" &
  curl "http://myphpserver/controller/action?valuesfromPHP$1=1&valuesfromPHP2=$2" &
  sleep 1
done
```

Assign the task from PHP how exactly i can send command line arguments with shell functions and let PHP not wait for the script to finish so that within less then 1 second after executing the script PHP is free, not frozen?:

```
$ php -R "shell_exec('/var/tmp/job1.sh value1 value2');"
```

How do you do that with PHP?

***EDIT:***

Step 1: start the job

```
  $l  = strtolower($this->data->language);
  $d1 = strtolower($rec->department1);
  $d2 = strtolower($rec->department2);
  $d3 = strtolower($rec->department3);
  $d4 = strtolower($rec->department4);
  shell_exec("/var/tmp/job1.sh {$l} {$d1} {$d2} {$d3} {$d4}");
```

Step 2: BASH to PHP trigger

```
  public function triggerdeviceAction() {
    $d1  = $_GET['department1'];
    $d2  = $_GET['department2'];
    $d3  = $_GET['department3'];
    $d4  = $_GET['department4'];
    $l   = $_GET['language'];

    $sql = "select *from sh_av_profile where
              `group` = 'agent' and
              status='free' and
              operator <> '' and 
              (
                department1=LOWER('{$rec->department1}') OR
                department2=LOWER('{$rec->department2}') OR
                department3=LOWER('{$rec->department3}') OR
                department4=LOWER('{$rec->department4}')                    
              )";
    $tmpres = $this->db->fetchAll($sql);      

    if (count($tmpres) > 0) {      
      foreach ($tmpres as $workstations) {
        $workstations['department1'] = strtolower($workstations['department1']);
        $workstations['department2'] = strtolower($workstations['department2']);
        $workstations['department3'] = strtolower($workstations['department3']);
        $workstations['department4'] = strtolower($workstations['department4']);

        $sql = "select *from sh_av_users where
                  username = LOWER('{$workstations['operator']}') and
                  status='online' and
                  (
                    language1=LOWER('{$l}') OR
                    language2=LOWER('{$l}') OR
                    language3=LOWER('{$l}')
                  ) and
                  department in (LOWER('{$workstations['department1']}'), 
                                 LOWER('{$workstations['department2']}'), 
                                 LOWER('{$workstations['department3']}'),
                                 LOWER('{$workstations['department4']}') 
                                )
                limit 1";
        $operatorFind = $this->db->fetchAll($sql);            
        if(count($operatorFind) > 0) {      
          try {
            $reject = new Application_Model_Device($workstations['ip'], 58888);
            $reject->sendKioskNoWait("calling");
          } catch(Exception $e) {

          }
          break;
        }
      }

    }

    echo "OK";
    exit;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1:

```
cat > /var/tmp/job1.sh <<\EOF
    #!/bin/bash
    i=0  
    while :
    do
      (( i++ ))
      a=$(curl -s --connect-timeout 1 'http://localhost/a/triggerdevice?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4&e=$5&f=$6&g=$7' | python -c 'import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);print obj["result"]')

      if [ a -eq "success"]; then
        echo "[OK]: $i"
        exit
      else
        echo "[FAIL]: $i"
      fi

      sleep 1

    done

EOF
chmod +x /var/tmp/job1.sh
```

Step 2: call it from php using shell_exec

```
shell_exec('/var/tmp/job1.sh tech dev root test NL 123 USER1');
```